# Which statistical model(s) can answer my question?

Tags: r, optimization, simulation

I have a large dataset (e.g. 1000) concerning nuclear radiation measurements (if I call it Z) where each data point is related to a barrel. These barrels must later on be deposited in a large container. Because of some spatial restrictions, I can only use a part of these barrels (e.g. 700). So, each Z-value is assigned to one barrel. For my problem, I must choose these 700 barrels as such that the mean of Z is close to 1. For sure, there are more than 1 possible combinations (700 barrels) where the mean of Z = 1.

I need to establish a simulation method by which I can find all the possible combinations of barrels (700 out of 1000 vessels) where my criteria is full filled (mean Z =1). I need to register all these combinations for analyzing other properties later on.

My Z-values (1000 values) are not normally distributed. I assume that my dataset is not parametric. However, maybe that is not so relevant to the problem.

For these 700 barrels I need a random selection with replacement where I already know the outcome (mean of Z=1). So, I need to optimize my selection (700 out of 1000) each time as such that the mean of Z becomes 1. How to do that? Which random selection method is useful in this case?

With replacement, because I would later also need to know which barrels have appeared the most and which ones are never selected etc.

Than you!

Comment: I and I'm sure many people who frequent this site could develop code for you to accomplish this task.  Or, probably better, one of us could teach you how to do so.  The problems are 1) what you request is a programming task, not a statistics question, and thus it's currently off-topic for this site and 2) you may have trouble finding people who will want to carry out this work for free.

Comment: Well thank you for your advice and tips! I didn't ask for full solution :) I just asked advise and some guidelines. For instance, should I use Monte Carlo simulation method etc. I'm sure there are also people who will share their knowledge for free just because science is beautiful and sharing is caring.  Any way, I do a little bit of R programming which I want to use to solve this problem. But, maybe not a bad idea to migrate my post to programming rooms. However, I still believe that it's not totally off statistics. Any ways, thanks!

Comment: In my experience, quick guidelines or tips are often of surprisingly little help in programming.  But I wish you well!

Comment: You are right but I also want to use this opportunity to learn more about different concepts and understand them better, although I've been misled too!!! ;) I see it as a challenge for myself :)